# Windows 10 installation using Boot Camp crashes in iMac with 'system thread exception not handled (igdkmd64.sys)'

Tags: imac, bootcamp, crash, macos

I've installed Windows 10 Pro in my iMac using Boot Camp but when the computer is on for 3-5 minutes, it crashes and shows BSOD with the error 'SYSTEM_THREAD_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED (igdkmd64.sys)'.

I've searched online; everyone saying this is caused by the built-in Intel HD graphics card driver but my iMac has dedicated graphic card AMD Radeon HD 6500 and the driver is updated to current version.

I followed these steps to fix the issue but still no luck.

1. Disabled the Intel HD driver from device manager under display adapters
2. Renamed the igdkmd64.sys from C:/Windows/system32 directory (once I completely deleted)
3. Uninstalled Intel HD graphics software from Programs and Features.

…but each time when I restart the PC, a new igdkmd64.sys file exists in the system32 directory.

The problem is Windows Update always tries to install that corrupted Intel HD driver in the system32 directory.

I couldn't continue to do any work on Windows, because I don't know when it's going to crash.

This issue was not there when I was running Windows 8.1 for nearly a year and half, but when I installed Windows 10 its started to happen.

Comment: Boot Camp does not officially support Windows 10 yet. The drivers haven't been updated in the Boot Camp Assistant.

Comment: is it better to revert back to windows 8.1? In General when apple going to release the new drivers for bootcamp?

Comment: I found a solution to hide the problematic drivers to update automatically in windows 10. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3073930

Comment: i dont know if this was solved for OP or not, but im having this exact same problem. only difference is that there is no intel driver under display adapters in device manager. there isnt much i can do since it gives me like 3 minutes then crashes...

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend downloading BlueScreenView or WhoCrashed to scan for minidump files and find out what caused this BSOD error. Based on the igdkmd64.sys, it's actually related to Intel Graphics driver.

carrona.org/drivers/search.php?id=igdkmd64.sys

But if you have tried uninstalling this driver and still getting this problem due to Windows forces itself to redownload and reinstall, then I would recommend you do it manually. That means go to:

downloadcenter.intel.com/Default.aspx

find for the driver, download and reinstall manually.

Besides, in some other cases, corrupted system files are also the cause that creates this BSOD error.

Source: [How To Fix System Thread Exception Not Handled Error](https://usefulpcguide.com/16886/fix-system-thread-exception-not-handled-error/)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to hide the problematic drivers to update automatically in windows 10. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3073930
Now my windows 10 is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try solution 4 from [this article](https://appuals.com/how-to-fix-igdkmd64-sys-bsod-on-windows-10/). Shortly, rename the `igdkmd64.sys` to something i.e. `igdkmd64.sys_backup` from MAC, and then try to reboot in Windows, it might go away.

Answer (score -1):

I have find a simple solution

The video is in Italian but i think is the best solutions and works 100%

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V3edX65w4ww

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  We're trying to find the best answers and those answers will provide info as to why they're the best. Explain why you think the link you provided will answer the question.  Links can change and become outdated so we prefer the answers to not just be a link.  See [answer] on how to provide a quality answer. - From Review

Answer (score -4):

Heres a solution that ccx worked for me. I typed this on a youtube video so I felt lazy restyling again so i took some screenshots for you guys.[image][image]

Comment: You could have just copy/paste the information instead of screenshots.

Comment: Please copy/paste as text. Information in pictures isn't accessible to the search function nor to people using screen readers.